# How to solve compatibility issue between jmathplot.jar (Plot2DPanel) and ORACLE java.awt. JFrame 8.31?

Tags: java, oracle, swing

I have used the jmathplot.jar  for 2D data plot as in the code below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import  org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel;

public  class MyPlot
{
//static Graphics g;
static public Plot2DPanel plot1;
static JFrame frame=new JFrame("a plot1 panel");

 public MyPlot()
  {
  frame.setSize(400,400);
  frame.setResizable(true);
  frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  frame.setLocation(900,150);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  plot1 = new Plot2DPanel();
  }

 // Method to show tha new plot, using the data in arrays x[] and y[].
 public  void show(double [] x,double []y)
  {  
  plot1.removeAllPlots();
  plot1.addLinePlot("my plot",x,y);
  plot1.setFixedBounds(0, 0, 1000);
  plot1.setFixedBounds(1, 0, 1000);
  frame.setContentPane(plot1);
  frame.repaint();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

The program works fine with Java Oracle SE _ jdk1.6.0_25 but when I updated to SE _ jdk1.8.0_31 this error:

```
setContentPane(java.awt.Container) in JFrame cannot be applied to (org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel)
```

Has been triggered under the code :

```
frame.setContentPane(plot1);
```

It is clear that a compatibility issue exist, but I am new with java and I don’t know how to overcome it and where to look for the answers. Thanks in advance to any help.

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: *"It is clear that a compatibility issue exist.."*  Is it?  If so, I'd be guessing the change is in `Plot2DPanel` as opposed to `JFrame`.  The `JFrame` content pane has been a `Container` ever since `JFrame` was available in the J2SE in version 1.2.  It sure hasn't changed that between 1.6 & 1.8.

Comment: As a side recommendation, your variables should not be static. Also your code has a Graphics variable which for me is a red flag that you may be trying to use Graphics in a dangerous way. There's almost never a need to have a field of this type.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , This Graphics variable is not intended for this code. I just forgot it after some old trys to find out a solution, but no hop. Sorry I will edit to remove it. Best regards..